# The scope body needs to be callable Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a scope in rails 4:

```
scope :available, {conditions: ["`model_name`.attribute NOT LIKE ?", "%**"]}
```

but I keep getting an error saying that `The scope body needs to be callable`

I have tried as well:

`scope :available, -> where ["'model_name'.attribute NOT LIKE ?", "%**"]`,

but it says here syntax error. what would be the right syntax in rails 4 then, or how to solve the error in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solved it quickyly, here is the solution:

```
scope :available, -> (attribute) { where("'model'.attribute NOT LIKE ?", "%**") }
```

thnks to this link: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/